# Monitoring a custom windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I've built a windows service application using Visual Studio .NET and C#. This service will be deployed on a few hundred machines and I'm looking for a solid way to monitor the application. By monitor, I mean, I just want to check to make sure that it's running, and check the status of a few settings on each client.

Is there a common method of doing this?

Comment: To handle monitoring, I ended up writing a rails application and deploying it to heroku. It was stupid simple and has been working great; for about 48 hours anyway..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is have each application "call home".  Create a single central application, preferably a web app, and have the remote applications make a small call to the central app on whatever interval you feel is necessary.  They can include the extra information you want to monitor.

Keep a list of where the application is deployed and if you don't get a call from any on the list within the expected timeframe, then you know it's offline.

If you can't change the actual application that you're monitoring, then write a small companion application that can run as a scheduled tasks and perform the same local checks and call back to the central application.

We do this with thousands of client machines worldwide and it works well.

Comment: This is a great idea. I wouldn't have thought of this!

Answer (score 5):

You could write a little monitor utility program that checks the service state via the SCM and provides a simple HTTP interface so you can poll the status. This would basically be just a big loop with some reporting if the service state changes.

```
while (true)
{
    string serviceName = "NameOfYourService";
    ServiceController Svc = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    if (Svc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        //Do reporting/set status here
    }
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of a monitoring tool like [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/), for example.